# "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'nome' cannot be null" y no se como arreglarlo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión de un formulario a una base de datos usando HTML, PHP y MySQL. Pero los datos que meto por el formulario no llegan hasta la base de datos, o se muestran en NULL (a pesar de que yo no deje nada vacío en el formulario.)

Este es mi formulario en html:

```
<fieldset>
<form action="config_novapadeiras.php" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="nome">Nome da padeira</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></center>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label>Localidade</label></center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Murtosa">Murtosa</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Estarreja">Estarreja</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Ovar">Ovar</center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="padeiramap">Link no Google Maps:</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" name="padeiramap" id="padeiramap"></center>
        </div>  
        <center><div class="form-group">
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </div></center>
    </form>
```

Este es mi script en PHP:

```
    if (isset($_POST["nome"]) && (isset($_POST['localidade']) && isset($_POST['GoogleMaps']))) {

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$localidade = $_POST["localidade"];
$padeiramap = $_POST["GoogleMaps"];

}

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "paonline";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

echo "A conexao funciono! Pronto o nosso equipo verificara o conteudo que tu emviaste e sera adicionado a web. Esto pode tardar um tempo, entre umas houras o ums dias.";

$sql = "INSERT INTO padeiras (nome, localidade, GoogleMaps)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if ( ! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss",
                       $nome,
                       $localidade,
                       $padeiramap);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

echo "Dados salvados.";
```

Y este es mi tabla en SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `padeiras` (
  `ID_Padeira` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `localidade` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `GoogleMaps` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Si, ya se que en portugués.

Aparentemente, el problema es que no hay data en $_POST (no se por que) y por alguna razón "nome" y "GoogleMaps" no están en $_POST (tampoco entiendo por que).

Por contexto: lo del Google Maps ya no es el link literal de la localización, sino solo una dirección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu instruccion `if` haces lo siguiente:

```
if (isset($_POST["nome"]) && (isset($_POST['localidade']) && isset($_POST['GoogleMaps']))) {

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$localidade = $_POST["localidade"];
$padeiramap = $_POST["GoogleMaps"];

}
```

pero el indice del array `$_POST['GoogleMaps']` no existe. En la instruccion `if` si uno de los tres elementos que se evaluan es `false` no se cumple la condicion y la instruccion siguiente seria un `else` o lo que fuere lo siguiente.
El caso es que en tu estructura HTML no defines lo que seria el indice `GoogleMaps` sino `padeiramap`

Comment: Gracias David, voy a intentar tu codigo. Pero otra pregunta: ¿Como hago para definir el indice de GoogleMaps maps (en caso de que lo necesite) para que no se me evalue como false? y que pueda ponerlo bien?

Comment: Simplemente cambias  `<center><input type="text" name="padeiramap" id="padeiramap"></center>`  por `<center><input type="text" name="GoogleMaps" id="padeiramap"></center>`

Comment: ¡Funciono! Al final si que resulta que puse el nombre mal. Por favor, acepte su cosa de color verde como muestra de mi gratitud. Puede que parezca exagerado, pero esta basura de codigo me tubo estresado desde el 25 de este mes.

Comment: Un placer ayudar. jaajaja