# "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'nome' cannot be null" Despues de intentar añadir una nueva variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hace unos meses pedi ayuda por aqui sobre mi proyecto. Pero ahora tengo que añadir una nueva variable y ahora mi proyecto da ese error cada vez que pruebo a añadir una nueva panaderia.

Mi formulario en HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<form action="config_novapadeiras.php" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="nome">Nome da padeira</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></center>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="nome">Paos</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="Paos" name="paos"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label>Localidade</label></center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Murtosa">Murtosa</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Estarreja">Estarreja</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Ovar">Ovar</center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="padeiramap">Link no Google Maps:</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" name="GoogleMaps" id="padeiramap"></center>
        </div>  
        <center><div class="form-group">
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </div></center>
    </form>
```

Esta es mi configuracion en php:

```
if (isset($_POST["nome"]) && (isset($_POST['Paos']) && (isset($_POST['localidade']) && (isset($_POST['GoogleMaps']))))) {

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$paos = $_POST["Paos"];
$localidade = $_POST["localidade"];
$padeiramap = $_POST["GoogleMaps"];

}

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "paonline";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

echo "A conexao funciono! Pronto o nosso equipo verificara o conteudo que tu emviaste e sera adicionado a web. Esto pode tardar um tempo, entre umas houras o ums dias.";

$sql = "INSERT INTO padeiras (nome, Paos, localidade, GoogleMaps)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if ( ! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss",
                       $nome,
                       $Paos,
                       $localidade,
                       $GoogleMaps);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

echo " Os Dados estao salvados, pode voltar ao Paonline fazendo click na flecha que va para a izquerda.";
```

Y esta es mi configuracion en MySQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE `padeiras` (
  `ID_Padeira` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `Paos` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `localidade` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `GoogleMaps` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
COMMIT;
```

El usuario @Sal ya me indico de que se me habia olvidade poner una ";" al final de {$paos = $_POST["Paos"]}. Ahora el mysqli me dice que el error esta en la linea 36, donde esta el mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

He intentado seguir la solucion de la ultima pregunta, pero aun asi seguia sin funcionar. Por contexto, aqui esta mi pregunta antigua: ["Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'nome' cannot be null" y no se como arreglarlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575993/uncaught-mysqli-sql-exception-column-nome-cannot-be-null-y-no-se-como-arreg)

Comment: Te falta `;` al final de la declaración de `$paos`.

Comment: @Sal Gracias, estoy ciego.

Comment: Pero el nuevo error que has puesta en la pregunta es **EXTREMADAMENTE CLARO**. Dime has al menos traducido el error? Intenta guiarte por [Esta Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/585098/61369).

Comment: @OCHOA Haber, entiendo que el error es sobre la variable "nome". Y que por alguna razon que no entiendo, la caja de texto de mi formulario de HTML no esta a enviar los textos que envio. Y no, no se a que te refieres con "traducir el error."

Comment: Justo eso, el error es claro y dice que el nombre esta en null. Bien, si ya sabes la raíz del problema, ya hiciste lo que te puse en mi comentario anterior? En el link dice lo que debes hacer para ir viendo que es lo que llega del formulario.

Comment: @OCHOA Lo siento, pero no entiendo la respuesta. ¿Se supone que tengo que copiar ese codigo y ponerlo en mi proyecto y luego cambiar los nombres? ¿Tengo que cambiar los $_POST por $_GET o es solo ese?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal definido el id **paos**. Debes hacer todo en una misma nomenclatura, en minúscula.

Esto lo he hecho en el mismo archivo.

```
if ($_POST) {
        if (isset($_POST["nome"]) && (isset($_POST['paos']) && (isset($_POST['localidade']) && (isset($_POST['GoogleMaps']))))) {

            $nome = $_POST["nome"];
            $paos = $_POST["paos"];
            $localidade = $_POST["localidade"];
            $padeiramap = $_POST["GoogleMaps"];

        }

        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

<form action="" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="nome">Nome da padeira</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="nome">Paos</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" id="paos" name="paos"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label>Localidade</label></center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Murtosa">Murtosa</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Estarreja">Estarreja</center>
            <center><input type="radio" name="localidade" value="Ovar">Ovar</center>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><label for="padeiramap">Link no Google Maps:</label></center>
            <center><input type="text" name="GoogleMaps" id="padeiramap"></center>
        </div>
        <center><div class="form-group">
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </div></center>
    </form>
```

El resultado es:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => 1
    [paos] => 2
    [localidade] => Murtosa
    [GoogleMaps] => 3
)
```

Cito lo que digo en la respuesta del comentario.

> Siempre, siempre, siempre, asegúrate como llegan los datos a tus archivos procesadores.

```
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

---

No olvides marcar la respuesta como **Aceptada** si resuelve tu problema/duda. :-)

Comment: Un momento, voy a provarlo.

Comment: He probado el codigo, ahora cuando meto esa informacion en mi formulario y lo envio, el formulario recarga su pagina y no aparece nada en la base de datos. ¿Se supone que tengo que quitar la ultima parte? La de echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: ¿Sigues hay? Sigo sin conseguir arreglar mi formulario. Lo que me has enviado no funciona. Solo hace que recarge la pagina y no guarda las cosas en el banco de datos.

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que estas atenido a que hagan todo por ti. Te he puesto un código que te permite ver como llegan tus datos al archivo procesador, arreglé el problema que tenias con la variable y campo del formulario mal declarado, esa era tu pregunta y la resolví. Igual ya tienes [Esta Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575993/uncaught-mysqli-sql-exception-column-nome-cannot-be-null-y-no-se-como-arreg) que es muy parecida a la actual. Pon de tu parte y cuando vea tu esfuerzo REAL no tendré ningún problema en seguir ayudándote.